# how to authenticate my login page with google account

Tags: android, authentication, email-validation

I have made a simple Login page for my application.For login I want to use email authentication to open my app front page.I have gone through various Blogs and Stackoverflow questions but can't found the appropriate result.
Please help me in doing this and elaborate the flow so that I can understand it clearly as I am new in android.